# Extending my ORDER BY in Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by, version, dql

I have a table that holds version numbers and I want to read them out naturally sorted.
This is no problem with raw SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM versions ORDER BY REPLACE(version, '.', '')+0 DESC
```

But if I write my query in Doctrine2 like this:

```
$qry = $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
  ->select('v')
  ->orderBy("REPLACE(v.version, '.', '')+0", 'DESC');
```

I only get

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message '[Syntax Error] line 0, col 100: Error: Expected end of string, got '('' in .......

Does anybody know how to write this query for Doctrine2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After long time struggeling, I realized that I needed to write out the query using `NativeQuery`:

```
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();
// do some result mapping here ....

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery("SELECT v.* FROM versions v ORDER BY REPLACE(v.version, '.', '')+0 DESC", $rsm);

$versions = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Alternatively you can add your own `REPLACE` string function.http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html  You can also install the doctrine extensions to add a set of predefined functions, that you can register in doctrine https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions